# Which would be best web based PDF editor using dot net core and javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

I am working with a requirement for one of the modules in the project(.Net Core) which comprises multiple PDF operations, like converting from PDF to HTML, then editing the HTML in a web view editor, finally converting it into a PDF.

**1. Spire pdf**

**Observation:**

I used existing code samples provided for spire pdf to convert from pdf to HTML and vice-versa. What I find missing in this editing the HTML editor in a web view, which allows me to add text, signature, etc in the editor.

**2. Sejda Online PDf editor tool (Javascript)**

**Observation:**

Developers link: Sejda.com/developers Online tool seems pretty cool but not able to integrate the editor in web view as trying to create token but the website says a user can be only registered with official email ids.
Pricing for this library is also a factor.
Please find screenshot below :

[image]

**3. PDF Tron(Javascript)**

**Observation:**

I used JavaScript code provided to use a web-based PDF editor. I am able to perform required editing operations with sample files provided like adding text, adding a signature, highlighting text.

Thank you for going through the article, feel free for any more suggestions, I would be happy to try out some more ways to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Also note that we don't do [product comparisons](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) here.

Comment: CORS is not a WebViewer issue, that is standard internet security. If you want to access PDF files on localhost, then run WebViewer yourself, its takes just a few minutes to run/host on localhost. See the Manual integration guide. Why is pricing an issue? If something does what you want, well documented, easy to setup, well supported, and saves you tons of time, that has its own value. Note that PDFTron WebViewer is based on the same SDK that powers XODO for Android, which has 4.7/5 from over 250k reviews on Android store. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en

Comment: @Ryan thank you for clarification and suggestion, working on resolving the issue.

Comment: If you have NPM installed, then this is the quickest way to get started locally. https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/manually/#run-samples

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, i am able to successfully run with node js setup, i understood the concept of setting up view viewer in client side, i wish same happens with .net core, as i need to integrate  in .net solution i am facing issues of loading a lib Simple_wasm/MemGrow.js.mem and getting error 404, i think i am missing something.

Comment: @Rayn i have posted the issue on stack overflow in which i have described it more technically [stackoverflow] (  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63161003/libraries-not-loading-for-pdftron-using-dotnet-core-and-javascript-issue-with-l). It would be helpful if i get any assistance for resolving issue in dot net core.

Comment: Great, the SDK works with any server technologies, so someone from the WebViewer SDK team will respond to your other SO question.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan for your response and support.

Comment: @Ryan Issue is resolved with my SO question, glad for your team support, i will update the article accordingly. Thanks!